# How to validate Savon Response in RubyMine log

Tags: ruby, rubymine, savon

I am running Savon in RubyMine, with a log in the event log. Is there a way to validate the response in the event log?

The Soap call I am running succeeds, but the response contains the tag , therefore affecting the remaining test steps. Is there a way in which I can stop the test if the response contains an error?

Input:

```
Globals: 
$soap_client_cumulus = Savon.client(
     wsdl: 'http://test.com/cumulus-ws/TestSoapService?wsdl',
     namespace: 'http://test.com/requests/cumulus/schema',
     env_namespace: :soapenv,
     namespace_identifier: :sch,
     pretty_print_xml: true,
     log: true,
     log_level: :debug,
     namespaces: {
    'xmlns:sch' => 'http://test.com/requests/cumulus/schema',
    'xmlns:draw' => 'http://test.com/data-dictionary/draw',
    'xmlns:priz' => 'http://test.com/data-dictionary/draw'})

And(/^I send the SOAP call 'close collection'$/) do
$soap_client_pymntmgr.call(:close_collection, message: {
    :"sch:collectionGroupId" => $group_id,
    :attributes! => {
        collectionGroupId: { 'xmlns' => 'http://test.com/requests/payment-manager/schema'}}})
```

And the response I am getting in the log:

```
Testing started at 16:25 ...
C:\Ruby23-x64\bin\ruby.exe -EUTF-8 -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\Ruby23-x64\bin/cucumber C:/Users/vande/RegressieTest/DrawTest/features/07-Close_the_collection.feature --format Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter --expand --color -r features
D, [2018-01-08T16:25:20.697496 #6680] DEBUG -- : HTTPI GET request to test.com (net_http)
I, [2018-01-08T16:25:20.887875 #6680]  INFO -- : SOAP request: http://test.com/payment-manager-ws/PaymentManagerSoapService
I, [2018-01-08T16:25:20.887875 #6680]  INFO -- : SOAPAction: "checkCollectionGroup", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 445
D, [2018-01-08T16:25:20.888375 #6680] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sch="http://test.com/requests/manager/schema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <sch:checkCollectionGroupRequest>
      <sch:collectionGroupId>22422</sch:collectionGroupId>
    </sch:checkCollectionGroupRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

D, [2018-01-08T16:25:20.898887 #6680] DEBUG -- : HTTPI POST request to test.com (net_http)
I, [2018-01-08T16:25:21.604963 #6680]  INFO -- : SOAP response (status 200)
D, [2018-01-08T16:25:21.605460 #6680] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <checkCollectionGroupResponse xmlns:ns6="http://test.com/data-dictionary/ticket" xmlns:ns5="http://test.com/data-dictionary/draw" xmlns:ns4="http://test.com/data-dictionary/prize" xmlns:ns3="http://test.com/data-dictionary/common" xmlns:ns2="http://test.com/data-dictionary/client" xmlns="http://test.com/requests/manager/schema">
      <success>false</success>
      <error>
        <code>10523</code>
        <message>Collection group is already closed.</message>
      </error>
    </checkCollectionGroupResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The SOAP call does not fail, but it still returns an error. Is there a way in which I can validate/expect a certain value in the response log?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... What has this got to do with your choice of text editor? Are you asking "how do I assert an API call does not contain a response, in rspec/minitest"? Can you provide a [mcve] of the problem - e.g. a sample good/bad API response?

Comment: @TomLord thank you, I've added the soap request that I am calling

Comment: Right... So as I suspected, all you need to do really is write an **assertion** that the XML does not contain `<message>Collection group is already closed.</message>`. (This has got nothing to do with RubyMine.) Have you written anything that parses the XML yet? This could be accomplished by a simple [`refute`](https://apidock.com/ruby/MiniTest/Assertions/refute) call. (But there are various libraries that do this; I don't want to dictate a specific approach. It would be best to align this check with your other assertions.)

Comment: @TomLord thank you for your suggestion! I haven't written anything to parse the XML yet, I am going to be looking into the refute call. Quite new to all of this, so thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Eventual answer:

```
  response = $soap_client_pymntmgr.call(:check_collection_group, message: {
      :"sch:collectionGroupId" => $group_id,
      :attributes! => {
          collectionGroupId: { 'xmlns' => 'http://test.com/requests/manager/schema'}}})


  groupresponse = response.body[:check_collection_group_response][:success]

  expect(groupresponse).to eq("true")
  end
```